# Can't restart from Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader, reboot

I am dual-booting Ubuntu 12.10 and Windows 8 Pro. Both run seamlessly but I've had the persistent issue of not being able to restart my machine properly from Ubuntu.

If I am on Ubuntu and hit the 'Restart..' option, the screen turns off and Ubuntu shuts down, but the computer never turns off and grub bootloader never shows on the screen. However, rebooting from Windows gets me to the bootloader as it should.

Turning off the machine completely with 'Shut down' works fine with both Ubuntu and Windows as well.

This issue was present even when I was dual booting Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7 Starter as well.

My computer is an Acer AOD257 with 2 GB RAM, Intel Atom N570 Processor. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Open a terminal window and issue the command "sudo reboot"  Does this work, or do you eventually see some error messages on a console screen?

Answer (score 1):

it seems to be firmware bug (aka its implementation according MS Windows implementation instead ACPI standard – how typical and probably unavoidable until Ubuntu bug #1 solved  :( ). Solution found here:

http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?PHPSESSID=giddkgurjnrsora9pgnvlfokh1&topic=170290.21

…just add:

```
reboot=efi
```

as boot parameter to kernel – tried on the same machine (differs only regarding slower CPU) and reboots are fine then :)

Enjoy your reboots! :D

P.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is a bug of ubuntu 12.10, cannot restart the laptop use click `restart` option on the power icon, mine is also like this, I use acer to run ubuntu too.

So, don't restart the computer, if it cannot go to the `gnome` welcome screen (stay on the splash), please uninstall your battery and re-power.